# Do Contains Check for JSon Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a Json Object array

```
   posturlContent = [
        { "Title": "Bbc news live", "Content": "<div>this is a test BBC </div>", "Uri": "http://bbc.co.uk" },
        { "Title": "CNN news live", "Content": "<div>this is a test CNN</div>", "Uri": "http://cnn.com" },
        { "Title": "Youtube news live", "Content": "<div>this is a test Youtube </div>", "Uri": "http://youtube.com" },
    ];
```

I have a JS array

```
uris =["http://cnn.com", "http://abcnews.com",...]
```

I need to check if any of the uris array element exist in posturlContent  Json obejct and also find the ones that does not exits. only way i know of to do is to do nested loop.

is there easier .inArray or Contains function i can use?

Comment: Do you just want to check or some other operations are there...??

Comment: some operation are there iif they are missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer without jQuery and without forEach incase you need old browser support...

```
for(var i =0; i<posturlContent.length; i++) {
  var detail = posturlContent[i];
  for(var j =0; j<uris.length; j++) {
    var uri = uris[j];
    if (detail.Uri === uri) {
      console.log('matched ' + detail.Uri);
    } else {
      console.log('didnt match ' + detail.Uri);
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to ignore case then instead of === you could use :-

```
if (new RegExp(uri, "i").test(details.Uri))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$.grep`:

```
$.grep(posturlContent, function(item){return item.Uri == siteUrl}).length > 0
```

If that is true the item is inside the array.

Then wrap that in `$.each`:

```
$.each(uris, function(){
    var siteUrl = this.valueOf();
    // Grep and do whatever you need to do.
})
```

You can remove the item like this:

```
$.each(uris, function(){
    var siteUrl = this.valueOf();
    posturlContent = $.grep(posturlContent, function(item){
        return item.Uri.toLowerCase() != siteUrl.toLowerCase();
    });
})
```

Note that we are now filtering for items that don't match the siteUrl.

Comment: is there a ignore case on Grep?

Comment: No, but you can use `function(item){return item.Uri.toLowerCase() == siteUrl.toLowerCase()})`.

Comment: if i find the match during grep, can i remove that item from uris array or since i am in the loop of the array i cannot remove it?

Comment: You can't just remove it if you use jQuery.each, since it caches the length and doesn't notice when the array gets shorter. You can use a for loop and iterate over it in reverse (so you don't have to worry about the length, you just continue until `i` is 0). Or you create a list of content objects and then loop over that list and remove the items (using `posturlContent.indexOf`).

Comment: Hang on, actually we are already using `grep` which is perfect for this. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What if create a url cache object? Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U94xT/1/

```
var posturlContent = [
    { "Title": "Bbc news live", "Content": "<div>this is a test BBC </div>", "Uri": "http://bbc.co.uk" },
    { "Title": "CNN news live", "Content": "<div>this is a test CNN</div>", "Uri": "http://cnn.com" },
    { "Title": "Youtube news live", "Content": "<div>this is a test Youtube </div>", "Uri": "http://youtube.com" },
];
var uris =["http://cnn.com", "http://abcnews.com"];

var urisCache = {}; // using object to avoid urls duplicates, that could occur using an array
for (var i = 0; i < posturlContent.length; i++) {
    var key = posturlContent[i]["Uri"];
    urisCache[key] = true; // or urisCache[key] = posturlContent[i]; if you need to access the corresponding entry from posturlContent
}

//now check if the uris array element exist in posturlContent
for (var i = 0; i < uris.length; i++) {
     alert(uris[i] in urisCache);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find exists by using JQuery grep and find nonExists by taking difference;

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
  return this.filter(function(i) {return !(a.indexOf(i) > -1);});
};

var exists = [];
jQuery.grep(posturlContent, function(n, i){
  var index = uris.indexOf(n.Uri);
  if(index >=0){
       exists.push(uris[index])
  }
});

var nonExists = uris.diff(exists)
```

Comment: Be careful extending the prototype of built-in objects. It's usually considered bad practice: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/

Comment: Thank you for your information but it can be rewritten as an independent function. Because that part is not related with the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep()` to find uri's that do and don't exist. I'm not sure how fast it is compared to writing your own loops, but it is certainly more straightforward

```
var posturlContent = [
        { "Title": "Bbc news live", "Content": "<div>this is a test BBC </div>", "Uri": "http://bbc.co.uk" },
        { "Title": "CNN news live", "Content": "<div>this is a test CNN</div>", "Uri": "http://cnn.com" },
        { "Title": "Youtube news live", "Content": "<div>this is a test Youtube </div>", "Uri": "http://youtube.com" },
    ];

var uris =["http://cnn.com", "http://abcnews.com"];

//keep track of URI's that exist and that are missing
var found = [];
var missing = [];

//for is faster than each()
for(var i=0; i<uris.length; i++) {
    found.concat($.grep(posturlContent, function(item){return item.Uri === uris[i]}, false));
    missing.concat($.grep(posturlContent, function(item){return item.Uri === uris[i]}, true));
}

//do something with found and missing urls
```